# Need help with redstone logic memory cells

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I need some advice if possible regarding making a memory cell, specifically what type of memory cell I should look at employing. I assume I want a T-Flip-Flop but I'm not too sure.

Basically the switch is going to be used as a track selector for a rail system, each location is connected to at most two other stations. What I'm attempting to do is probably best explained in a picture:
[image]

As you can see I would like to have the current state of particular junction saved in a particular state. When a button is pressed it toggles the state of that lever which is then saved again. I'm assuming for this I would want a T-Flip-Flop switch and I would need to feed the input buttons from all stations to meet at the input end of this switch, would that be correct?

Answer (score 4):

Was able to answer my own question I think articulating it in words helped. In anyone else is coming across this then a flip flop switch will indeed work, in order for a button at any location to work simply feed it into the input end before the switch and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution for this is a toggle switch.

Requires:
1x Redstone Block

2x Sticky Piston

2x Redstone Repeater

1x Any block (e.g. cobble)

`+` Extra redstone to connect to stations.

The redstone block will toggle between state 1 and 2 every time a button is pressed.

[image: Image of Toggle Switch]

Answer (score 2):

A simple T Flip Flop with all the inputs ORed together does just fine. So yes, you are exactly correct.

Although, one thing that I'd recommend is a redstone lamp that shows the current state of the T Flip Flop, if these stations are far enough apart, this means that you need to run a second wire that displays the state of the T Flip Flop.